# Razor HTML dropdown list helper not selecting matching value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view where I am creating a dropdown list. The list populates properly, but will not select the matching item for the page I'm editing.
On this page I am editing a Sermon record. The sermon model has the id of the series that it belongs to. I have confirmed that the `series_id` in the sermon record, and the matching one in the dropdown list are both "1". I did this by debugging `model.sermon.Series_ID, and confirming that it was "1", and using Inspect in Chrome, I saw that there is a "1" on one of the items in the dropdown list.

Can anyone tell me why the dropdown list isn't selecting the matching series? There is no "selected" attribute being produced even though the number
that matches is present.

View

```
@model SermonLibraryManager.ViewModels.ViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.sermon.Series_ID, new SelectList(Model.seriesList, "Series_ID", "Series_Title"), "-- Select --")
```

ViewModel

```
namespace SermonLibraryManager.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public SermonModel sermon;
        public List<SermonModel> sermonList;
        public SeriesModel series;
        public List<SeriesModel> seriesList;
    }
}
```

SermonModel

```
public class SermonModel
{
    public int Sermon_ID { get; set; }
    public string Series_Title { get; set; }
    public int Series_ID { get; set; }
    public string Sermon_Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Sermon_Date { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
    public string Topic { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string UStream_ID { get; set; }
    public string Vimeo_ID { get; set; }
    public int? Main_Speaker { get; set; }
}
```

SeriesModel

```
public class SeriesModel
{
    public int Series_ID { get; set; }
    public string Series_Title { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Please include the HTML generated

Comment: The simple way is to add `{ get; set; }` on your `ViewModel` class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a very good discussion with **@Stephen Muecke**, I'm editing the answer in order to avoid other users to be confused.

The problem is that your view model is using a public field instead of a property and model binding doesn't work with fields, so in practice this is the same as using the `Html.DropDownList()` helper method and this method accepts any value as the selected value in the select list.

If you convert your fields into properties in your view model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public SermonModel sermon { get; set; }
    public List<SermonModel> sermonList { get; set; }
    public SeriesModel series { get; set; }
    public List<SeriesModel> seriesList { get; set; }
}
```

The the only thing  you need to do is to call the `Html.DropDownListFor()` method and model binding will take care of everything for you:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.sermon.Series_ID, new SelectList(Model.seriesList, "Series_ID", "Series_Title"), "-- Select --")
```

Another good advice is never use data models in your view models, so the best solution will be to have an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in the viewmodel and generate the Drop Down in the view.

Thanks to @Stephen Muecke for  pointing out the real issue.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That was it! Simple noob mistake. Thank you!

Comment: Adding another property is not a proper solution. Adding getter-setter is.

Comment: This is completely wrong. The `object selectedValue` is ignored by the `DropDownListFor()` - internally the method generates a new `SelectList` and sets the selected value based on the value of the property its binding to (thats how model binding works). The only time that setting the `selectedValue` is respected is when not binding to a model property - e.g. `@Html.DropDownList("NotAProperty", new SelectList(....` (OP's issue is that the model contains fields, not properties)

Comment: @StephenMuecke no it's not. I've test it before posting the answer and it works as expected. Could you please, point to some official documentation link where such a thing is mentioned?

Comment: What I suggest you do is study the [source code](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/SelectExtensions.cs), in particular the `private` helper methods at the end of the file. And you did not test it correctly :)

Comment: And refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ho9n49) to prove it. Note that the value of the property that the dropdown is bound to is `2`, and the `SelectList` constructor includes `selectedValue` set to `3` - the option with the value of `3` is not selected :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thanks for the info. Nevertheless, take a look at [this](https://github.com/ktamayop/DropDownListSample) sample. Note the selected value been set using some other property in the viewmodel, also the viewmodel has still fields, not properties, and the item been selected is the item with value 4, not 3. :-)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not going to download a run your your app (I don't even know which piece of code I should be looking at). Create a DotNetFiddle if you want to show me something. And I guarantee that setting `selectedValue` is ignored (unless your generating dropdownlists in a loop)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125956/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-karel-tamayo).

Comment: Thank you for the update. As I am still learning C#, I didn't even see the missing get/set. Nor did I think about the difference between the two (field vs property). I do know the difference between the two, but in all my effort to figure out what was going wrong, I didn't even see it (forest for the trees?)  I appreciate all who jumped in to help! :o)